# NGINX - Friendly URL

Tags: regex, nginx

I have a website pingrglobe.com and it's blog, pingrglobe.com/blog... I am stuck when it comes to NGINX since I am fairly new and got no idea where to search for help.

So, on the blog URLs look like this:
http://www.pingrglobe.com/blog/blogpost?post=4
But I would love:
http://www.pingrglobe.com/blog/blogpost/4

How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Let us know the software your blog is using, if any.

Comment: Custom on an Ubuntu server. :)

Comment: You'll need to construct a "rewrite" to capture requests to `/blog/blogpost/4` and redirect it to `/blog/blogpost?post=4` ... http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this rewrite condition a try:

```
rewrite ^/blog/blogpost/([\d]+)/?$ /blog/blogpost?post=$1
```

Place it in your `server` block.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know how it goes, thanks Julian!

Comment: Whoops, forgot the qs. Try again.

Comment: Well now I get:
404 Not Found

Comment: ... and now it's time for you to start tweaking the regular expression :)

Comment: How? Where would I start? I am new to NGINX :/

Comment: I googled around and I got it working from your code: http://www.pingrglobe.com/blog/blogpost/4